# What is the future of the bitcoins?

Tags: market

It said that the last two years, bitcoins has been losing value. What would happen in the future? And what is the reason of this?

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't answer either of the questions. Why is it accepted?

Comment: That's one way to fake credit on your other account...

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, no one knows. Assumptions or guesses about the future are exactly that, just assumptions. We could however look at what could make the price go up or down.

**A new cryptocurrency**

This might make the price of bitcoin go down, since there would be less people working with bitcoins and more people working with a new 'altcoin'. However, most people get into altcoins by buying bitcoins and then trading bitcoins for altcoins, so this is also in a way a positive thing for bitcoin.

**Early adopter(s) cashing out**

The people who got into Bitcoin pretty early on (people who bought 1000 BTC for $1 or less) might cash out at any time, pushing the price down. Most 'whales' cashing out 'dump' their bitcoins, instead of slowly selling bunches of 10 BTC at a time, so they do impact the worldwide price.

**More people getting into bitcoin**

This would make the price go up. The amount of possible available coins stays the same (21 million) and the amount of available coins slowly increases. If there is a larger increase in users than there is an increase in coins, there will be a rise in the price.

This can also reverse, if there are not enough new users (in a month / a year) the price will go down for the same reason.

**The mining reward halving**

This causes the bitcoins mined per block to halve, making the release of bitcoins go slower. This means the supply will slow down a bit. If the demand would stay the same and/or rise, the price would rise.

[Please edit this answer and add more possible reasons]

Answer (score -3):

Really this is a good question, in fact as @Mr Jones said, no ones can say what are going to happen in the bitcoins markets. 
Basically you have to think how the bitcoins are create: thanks to the computer algorithms.
We know that the last years bitcoin has been losing value, as you can check in the charts,(this page is very usefull http://bitcoincharts.com/markets/)
You should have some knowdelge about technical chart analysis (you can learn more about [this](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:overview:technical_analysis)). 
Let`s do it to the bitcoin chart:
[image]
You can see that the bitcoin is loseing value.